# NotImplementedError: font module not available PyGame Mac

Tags: python, macos, fonts

In this code, I referenced the font, and python show me this problem.

I've seen other people have a similar problem, but nothing helped me. I understand that the problem is in the path to the file on line 12, but I don't know how to solve it.

- Python - 64 bit,
- pyGame - 64 bit,
- macOS Mojave.

My error and my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lewstefanevskij/Desktop/TER/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    myfont = pygame.font.Font('fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf',40)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(missing_msg)
NotImplementedError: font module not available (ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/font.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/.dylibs/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found)
```

```
import pygame

pygame.init() # ініціалізація
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,300)) # розмір вікна
pygame.display.set_caption('GTA 5') # назва вікна
icon = pygame.image.load('images/icon.png') #завантаження фотки
pygame.display.set_icon(icon) # встановлення фотки

square = pygame.Surface((50,170)) # параметри квадрата
square.fill('Blue') # колір квадрата

myfont = pygame.font.Font('fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf',40)
text_surface = myfont.render('Lev',False,'Yellow',)

running = True
while running:

    pygame.draw.circle(square,'Red',(10,17),10)
    screen.blit(square,(200,100)) #створюєм квадрат
    screen.blit(text_surface,(100,100))

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()w
```

I tried reinstalling python, Sysfont, match_font and downloading python local.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled python 3.11 and pygame 2.1.3, then installed python 3.8.5 and pygame 2.1.2.

Comment: You could improve the English a bit so it is easier to understand that you spotted your problem and found the solution.  E.g. "I fixed this in the end by deleting python 3.11 and pyjama 2.1.3 and instead installed python 3.8.5 and pyjama 2.1.2"